# Are (Digital Ocean) VPS droplets genuine? How can I trust a third party VPS?

Tags: debian, vps

I have some Digital Ocean debian based droplets and I wonder how far they are from a vanilla debian installation. As far as I understand it's technically possible that some additional software (malicious or not) has been installed in the droplet.

How can I be sure and trust that a freshly created Debian droplet contains only Debian free software?

To be clear I have no reason to doubt Digital Ocean and the same question is valid for any VPS provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, all cloud providers run some sort of agent software on their (your) VMs. How else would they be able to give you monitoring data, reset root password, add volumes, etc.? It's also standard to set first-boot options via cloud-config files, and Digital Ocean does that as well. On Digital Ocean servers, cloud-config files for the droplet's initialization options are in /var/lib/cloud/instances/

Cloud-config runs only on first boot. It's not active after that, so the left-over files aren't hurting anything or changing how the server works.

There are a few packages installed on Digital Ocean's debian droplets that I prefer to remove, such as the telnet client and other desktop odds and ends. But that's personal preference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it helps a lot, thanks. I'm trying to deepening more this topic out and I wonder if DO (or any other provider) publishes some detailed information about the software that they install. I'll add back if I find something.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you can give it an upvote in that case, I'd appreciate it. Trying to build enough rep to participate.

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough reputation yet. I will for sure asap